# Why the Auth::attempt method always returns false?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to do a basic authentication and when I try to authenticate the user,but `Auth :: attempt` method returns false

**Blade**

```
   {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'usuario')) }}

                <input type="text" class="text"  id="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo" {{(Input::old('email')) ? 'value ="'. Input::old('email').'"' : '' }}>
                <p>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</p>
                <input type="text" class="text"  id="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" >
                <p>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</p>


            {{ Form::submit('Ingresar', array('class' => 'bg1')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

**Controller**

```
class UsuarioController extends BaseController{
public function doLogin(){
$rules = array(
                'email' => 'required|email',
                'password' => 'required'
                );
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
if($validator->fails()){
    return Redirect::to('usuario')->withErrors($validator)->withInput(Input::except('password'));
}else{

    $userdata = array(
        'email' => Input::get('email'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
        );

    if(Auth::attempt($userdata)){
        return View::make('hello');
    }else{
        return Redirect::to('usuario');
    }

}
}
}
```

**Auth**

```
'driver' => 'database',
'model' => 'Usuario',
'table' => 'Usuario',
```

**Model**

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;
class Usuario extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface{
protected $table = 'Usuario';
protected $primaryKey = 'idUsuario';
protected $hidden = array('Contrasena');
protected $fillable = array(
                    'Nombre',
                    'Apellido',
                    'Tipo',
                    'password',
                    'email',
                    'Fono',
                    'Foto'
                    );
}
```

The code always returns false and redirects me to login, use incorrect data when the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many reasons that can make it return false every time:

1) Your password is not correctly stored/hashed, you **must** hash it with:

```
Hash::make($password);
```

This is a way to create users and store passwords correctly hashed by Laravel:

```
$user = new User;

$user->email = 'example@domain.com';

$user->password = Hash::make('thePasswordToBeHashed');

$user->save();
```

2) Your password column size has not enough room to store a hashed password. It must be at least 60 bytes long, but migrating it with:

```
$table->string('password');
```

Is a good practice, because if this size somehow changes in the future you won't have problem.

3) You don't have a user with the e-mail (Correo) you are trying to login. Double check it, because this is more frequent than we think. And you can also try to do it manually to see if it really works:

```
$userdata = array(
    'Correo' => 'youremail@domain.com',
    'Password' => 'password'
);

dd( Auth::attempt($userdata) );
```

4) Data is not being correctly passed by your form, check if your form really works, by dying it with:

```
dd(Input::all());
```

And check if you get the correct data.

5) You have a validation, so the problem could be on it. Add another die message to be sure:

```
if($validator->fails())
{
    dd('Validation is failing!');

    ...
}
```

6) From the comment:

```
$userData = array('email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password'));            

return (string) Auth::attempt($userData));
```

7) Try to create a different user manually:

```
$user = new User;

$user->email = 'example@domain.com';

$user->password = Hash::make('passwordExample');

$user->save();
```

And login with it:

```
$userData = array('email' => 'example@domain.com', 'password' => 'passwordExample');            

return (string) Auth::attempt($userData));
```

Comment: 1. I changed that y nothing happend.
2. I doent use migration in my application, and password's size is 100
3. I fixed it in the model and data base and nothing happend.
4. I recieve correctly tall the input.
5. The validation doenst fail.

Comment: So in 3. you still get nothing (false)? If 3 doesn't work, nothing will work.

Comment: ``$userData = array('email' => Input::get('email'),'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'))); return Auth::attempt($userData)``  show....``The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.``

Comment: You have to cast it to string. And you don't need to hash to attempt, just to store in database. Edited to show how.

Comment: You still have a problem in your database. Check if the password is really hashed. And, please, show us your user creation controller method.

Comment: I do not have a method or a controller to create user, the only user that I created in the database were inserted by force from phpmyadmin

Comment: PHPMYadmin hashes won't work for Laravel, you have to do method 7 to creat your users, otherwise the hash will not match and you won't be able to login.

Comment: Basically your problem is in the item 1.